# Evaluate integral from first principles

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

Evaluate integral $\int_C z^3$ from first principals, where $C$ is the straight line joining $1+i$ and $2+4i$.

From integrating it normally I got

$$\int_{1+i}^{2+4i}z^3 \,dz = \frac {z^4} {4}\Big|_{1+i}^{2+4i} = \frac{(2+4i)^4} {4}-\frac{(1+i)^4}{4}.$$

So I believe I should get the same answer when solving using from first principles.

Is this the first principal integration formula we are supposed to use?

$$\int_a^b {f(x)}\,dx = \lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{i=1} ^{n} f(a+ \frac{b-a}{n}i)(\frac{b-a}{n})$$

I tried using this but I am unsure of where to being. Can someone show me how to solve this from the first principal properly?

Comment: "First principles" not "first principal."  I suppose they want you to split the integral into real and imaginary parts and write it in terms of two real integrals, using the definition $\mathrm{d}z=\mathrm{d}x+i\mathrm{d}y$.

Comment: I don't think they want you to go all the way back to Riemann sums.  Just the definition of a complex line integral.